# WPF and Metro Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Perhaps you could help with this, I already tried several different ways but I m unable to achieve the desired results...

Using MahApps, I want to use ComboBoxes to change the applied theme to my WPF Window.

I used some of the code from MahApps Demo and adaped to my Project/Solution. I am able to load the Theme Names and the Accent Names to the ComboBoxes in my project, but now, when I change the selection in these comboboxes I want to call the command that exists in "AccentColorMenuData Class" using code behing in  "SelectionChanged" events.

So My BaseModel code is:

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            Debug.Write($"--- CLASS ViewModel Called OnPropertyChanged for object: {propertyName} -------- \n");
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel is:

```
namespace WPFApplication.Ui
{
    public class AccentColorMenuData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Brush BorderColorBrush { get; set; }
        public Brush ColorBrush { get; set; }

        private ICommand changeAccentCommand;

        public ICommand ChangeAccentCommand
        {
            get { return this.changeAccentCommand ?? 
                    (changeAccentCommand = new SimpleCommand { CanExecuteDelegate = x => true, ExecuteDelegate = x => this.DoChangeTheme(x) }); }
        }

        protected virtual void DoChangeTheme(object sender)
        {
            var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
            var accent = ThemeManager.GetAccent(this.Name);
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, accent, theme.Item1);
        }
    }

    public class AppThemeMenuData : AccentColorMenuData
    {
        protected override void DoChangeTheme(object sender)
        {
            var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
            var appTheme = ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(this.Name);
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, theme.Item2, appTheme);
        }
    }

    public class RemoteSystemsViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public List<AccentColorMenuData> AccentColors { get; set; }
        public List<AppThemeMenuData> AppThemes { get; set; }

        public RemoteSystemsViewModel()
        {
            // create accent color menu items for the demo
            this.AccentColors = ThemeManager.Accents
                                            .Select(a => new AccentColorMenuData() { Name = a.Name, ColorBrush = a.Resources["AccentColorBrush"] as Brush })
                                            .ToList();

            // create metro theme color menu items for the demo
            this.AppThemes = ThemeManager.AppThemes
                                           .Select(a => new AppThemeMenuData() { Name = a.Name, BorderColorBrush = a.Resources["BlackColorBrush"] as Brush, ColorBrush = a.Resources["WhiteColorBrush"] as Brush })
                                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My Control s Code behind (Note I already have an event function for both Comboboxes)

```
public partial class ConfigurationView : UserControl
    {
        private readonly RemoteSystemsViewModel _viewModel;

        public RemoteSystemsView()
        {
            _viewModel = new RemoteSystemsViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }

        void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

And finally my XAML for the comboboxes inside the control

<

```
ComboBox  x:Name="AccentColorsComboBox"
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding AccentColors, Mode=OneWay}"
                                           SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                           DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                           SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
                                           />
                                <ComboBox  x:Name="AppThemesComboBox"
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding AppThemes, Mode=OneWay}"
                                           SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                           DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                           SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
                                           >

                                </ComboBox>
```

AS I said, the Comboboxes are populated Ok with the correct information , but now, when I change 1 or the other I want to modified the applied theme.

I already tried many different things to achieve this but with no success, perhaps you can give a "hand"... :)

Thank you.

Update: Using Dustin Suggestion

```
void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            string AccentName = this.AccentColorsComboBox.SelectedValue as string;
            string ThemeName = this.AppThemesComboBox.SelectedValue as string;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccentName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ThemeName))
            {
                //Debug.Write($"{AccentName} - {ThemeName}\n");
                ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent(AccentName), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(ThemeName));
            }
}
```

I meanwhile i also did:

```
void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        ComboBox control = (ComboBox)sender;
        String name = control.Name;
        int index = -1;
        index = control.SelectedIndex;
        if (index > -1)
        {
            var vm = this.DataContext as RemoteSystemsViewModel;

            if (name == "AccentColorsComboBox")
            {
                //Call command from viewmodel     
                if ((vm != null) && (vm.AccentColors[index].ChangeAccentCommand.CanExecute(null)))
                    vm.AccentColors[index].ChangeAccentCommand.Execute(null);
            }
            else
            {
                //Call command from viewmodel     
                if ((vm != null) && (vm.AppThemes[index].ChangeAccentCommand.CanExecute(null)))
                    vm.AppThemes[index].ChangeAccentCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }

    }
```

Now My problem with both approaches is when I try to change the theme 2 consecutive times, it only changes the theme if I change once then gogo back and make another selection and change it again... The Accents change OK at firs try.

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION IN C# (THANK YOU DUSTIN FOR THE HELP)**

For XAML and CONTROLS the Code is the same as Dustin posted in his post.

For C# where it goes:

**New Object:**

```
public class ApplicationAccentColor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush { get; set; }
    }
```

**VIEWMODEL + CONSTRUCTOR:**

```
public class SystemsViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        /// Open Project Settings and select Settings, then add the following values:
        /// Name= ApplicationThemeName Type = String Scope= User Value = BaseDark
        /// Name= ApplicationAccentName Type = String Scope= User Value = Blue
        /// </summary>

        public IEnumerable<AppTheme> AppThemes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationAccentColor> AccentColors { get; set; }

        public AppTheme SelectedTheme
        {
            /// Project Global Settings variable
            /// Name= ApplicationThemeName Type = String Scope= User Value = BaseDark
            /// Name= ApplicationAccentName Type = String Scope= User Value = Blue
            get
            {
                /// Get default Values from global varable settings
                return ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(Settings.Default.ApplicationThemeName);
            }
            set
            {
                /// Get default Values from global varable settings, and check if they are the same
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(Settings.Default.ApplicationThemeName), value))
                    return;

                /// Save the new value to global settings variable
                Settings.Default.ApplicationThemeName = value.Name;
                Settings.Default.Save();

                /// Apply the Theme
                ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent(SelectedAccent.Name), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(value.Name));
            }
        }

        public ApplicationAccentColor SelectedAccent
        {
            /// Project Global Settings variable
            /// Name= ApplicationThemeName Type = String Scope= User Value = BaseDark
            /// Name= ApplicationAccentName Type = String Scope= User Value = Blue
            get
            {
                //foreach (ApplicationAccentColor acc in AccentColors)
                //{
                //    if (acc.Name == Settings.Default.ApplicationAccentName)
                //    {
                //        return acc;
                //    }
                //}
                //return new ApplicationAccentColor();

                /// Get default Values from global varable settings
                foreach (ApplicationAccentColor acc in from acc1 in AccentColors where acc1.Name == Settings.Default.ApplicationAccentName select acc1)
                {
                    return acc;
                }
                return new ApplicationAccentColor();
            }
            set
            {
                /// Get default Values from global varable settings, and check if they are the same
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(ThemeManager.GetAccent(Settings.Default.ApplicationAccentName).Name, value.Name))
                    return;

                /// Save the new value to global settings variable
                Settings.Default.ApplicationAccentName = value.Name;
                Settings.Default.Save();

                /// Apply the Theme
                ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent(value.Name), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(SelectedTheme.Name));
            }
        }


        public SystemsViewModel()
        {
            AppThemes = ThemeManager.AppThemes;
            AccentColors = ThemeManager.Accents.Select(a => new ApplicationAccentColor
            {
                Name = a.Name,
                ColorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)a.Resources["AccentColorBrush"]
            }).ToList();


        }

    }
```

APP.cs (To Load Latest Settings at start UP)

```
//Loading Values from Global Variables set in Application Settings
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                        ThemeManager.GetAccent(Settings.Default.ApplicationAccentName.ToString()),
                                        ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(Settings.Default.ApplicationThemeName.ToString()));
```

**Thank you Dustin for your Help :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you change the theme/accent

```
ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Windows.Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent(AccentName), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(ThemeName))
```

You are already using that in DoChangeTheme of AccentColorMenuData and AppThemeMenuData : AccentColorMenuData

UPDATE/EDIT:
Here is how I implemented this same type of functionality. It's in VB but you can easily convert it if need be. Mine is in a flyout on the main window as part of settings:

**Requires that you create Settings in the project that way this color info persists through sessions. You can do that in VS b opening My Project and selecting Settings. You add the following settings:**

- **Name= ApplicationThemeName Type= String Scope= User Value=BaseDark**
- **Name= ApplicationAccentName Type=String Scope= User Value=Blue**

Of course you can have your defaults be whatever.

New Object:

```
Public Class ApplicationAccentColor
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ColorBrush As SolidColorBrush
End Class
```

In your viewModel------------------------

Props:

```
Public Property AppThemes As New List(Of AppTheme)

Public Property AccentColors As New List(Of ApplicationAccentColor)

Public Property SelectedTheme As AppTheme
    Get
        Return ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(MySettings.Default.ApplicationThemeName)
    End Get
    Set
        If ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(MySettings.Default.ApplicationThemeName) Is Value Then Exit Property
        MySettings.Default.ApplicationThemeName = value.Name
        MySettings.Default.Save()
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Windows.Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent(SelectedAccent.Name), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(value.Name))
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SelectedAccent As ApplicationAccentColor
    Get
        For Each acc As ApplicationAccentColor In From acc1 In AccentColors Where acc1.Name = MySettings.Default.ApplicationAccentName
            Return acc
        Next
        Return New ApplicationAccentColor()
    End Get
    Set
        If ThemeManager.GetAccent(MySettings.Default.ApplicationAccentName).Name is value.Name Then Exit Property
        MySettings.Default.ApplicationAccentName = value.Name
        MySettings.Default.Save()
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Windows.Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent(value.Name), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(SelectedTheme.Name))
    End Set
End Property
```

Constructor:

```
AppThemes = ThemeManager.AppThemes
AccentColors = ThemeManager.Accents.Select(Function(a) New ApplicationAccentColor With {.Name = a.Name, .ColorBrush = a.Resources("AccentColorBrush")}).ToList()
```

XAML:

Control resource:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AppThemeItemsTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Resources[WhiteColorBrush]}" Stroke="{Binding Resources[BlackColorBrush]}"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AccentColorItemsTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding ColorBrush}"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Actual controls:

```
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Label Content="Theme"/>
            <ComboBox Width="125" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AppThemeItemsTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding AppThemes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTheme}"/>
            <Label Content="Accent"/>
            <ComboBox Width="125" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccentColorItemsTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding AccentColors}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccent}"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding RefreshDirectoriesFiles}" Margin="0,20,0,0" Content="Refresh Directories/Files"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you, I made an update in the original post, please have a look at both approaches, what do you think is best (I was trying to rewrite the same code), and why is the Themes not changing after I try to change it consecutive second time.

Comment: You can really simplify everything by not using code behind. Also, do you plan on persisting the colors through sessions or does the user have to change the color everytime they launch the application?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to save applied theme and color.

Comment: Sorry.. That's LINQ.

Comment: For Each acc As ApplicationAccentColor In AccentColors
    If acc.Name = MySettings.Default.ApplicationAccentName Then
     Return acc
    End If
   Next
   Return New ApplicationAccentColor()

Comment: in this one I`m getting Cannot Convert ResourceDictionary to Solid Color Brush...

Comment: AppThemes = ThemeManager.AppThemes;
            AccentColors = ThemeManager.Accents.Select(a => new ApplicationAccentColor
            {
                Name = a.Name,
                ColorBrush = a.Resources
            }).ToList()

Comment: if I use - ColorBrush = a.Resources("AccentColorBrush") - throws error it cannot be used like a method

Comment: Ok, everything implemented, the only problem now is that is not saving applied settings....

Comment: Just loop through ThemeManager.Accents and create a new ApplicationAccentColor. Set the new applicationaccentcolor.name and colorbrush. Then add the new applicationaccentcolor to the AccentColors list. Thats what the line is doing but uses LINQ for inline code.

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not saving through sessions? Make sure you went into the project settings and added those settings i mentioned. They have to be present in the project.

Comment: Is just not saving through sessions, but, the Comboboxes have the latest  values set before, so to solve this I wen to the App.xaml and loaded the Global values set at App level, and now is loading the correct values at startup, THANK YOU!!! :) - I`ll share the code in C# here that I converted from your code (I had to make some minor changes to make it work). Thank you once again :)

Comment: Original Post Updated, Thank You Dustin :)